# Upload picture from android to server HttpPost deprecated

Tags: android, image, upload, server, deprecated

I am making an android app that allows users to upload pictures to the server. The code works but since the HttpPost methods are deprecated I tried to update the solution but the updated solution does not work. The weird thing is that that same updated solution (with different parameters) is the one that I am using to log in users and it works, so I have no idea what the error could be. Anybody knows what I am missing?

Updated solution: 
The image does not upload but it does not give any errors

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);


        //PRUEBAS
        try {
            String urlSt = "http://phoenixcoding.tk/SavePicture.php";
            URL url = new URL(urlSt);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("name", name)
                    .appendQueryParameter("image", encodedImage);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            connection.connect();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
   }
```

Deprecated solution: it works

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://phoenixcoding.tk/SavePicture.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
  }
```

SavePhoto.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$image = $_POST["image"];

$decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");
file_put_contents("pictures/" . $name . ".JPG", $decodedImage);?>
```

Comment: please, read logcat logs ... `new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("name", name).build()` will throw [UnsupportedOperationException](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/Uri.java#L1522) ... using Uri.Builder is not the way how we are sending url encoded form via URLConnection API

Comment: It is not throwing any exception... and I used that exact same code to send user and password data to the server and it worked the thing is that for some reason it does not work with pictures and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after lots of trying I finally made it work. I don't know the reason, but adding an input stream after opening the connection made the pictures upload.

```
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(strLine + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
```